# What causes AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'da'?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, cost-path

I have a shapefile "selected_polygons.shp" that contains 2000 polygons. I would like to select each polygon contained in the shapefile by using a search cursor in order to apply the function "CostDistance" for each polygon.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\LCP"
arcpy.env.extent = "costs.tif"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("selected_polygons.shp",("*")) as rowsInPatches_start:

for rowStart in rowsInPatches_start:        

 ID_patch_start = rowStart.getValue("GRIDCODE") 

 ## Define SQL expression for the fonction Select Layer By Attribute
 expressionForSelectInPatches_start = "GRIDCODE=%s" % (ID_patch_start) 

 # Process: Select Layer By Attribute in Patches_start
 arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("selected_patches.shp", "Selected_patch_start", expressionForSelectInPatches_start)

 # Process: Cost Distance
 outCostDist=CostDistance("Selected_patch_start", "costs.tif", "", "outCostLink.tif")

 # Save the output 
 outCostDist.save("outCostDist.tif")
```

The problem is that I obtain a error message when I use:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("selected_polygons.shp",("*")) as rowsInPatches_start:
```

Here is my error message:

```
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'da'
```

Comment: Just verifying that you are in fact using 10.1 and not 10? `da` only works upwards of 10.1

Comment: No problem, it was just the wrong version?

Comment: Yes, It was just the wrong version.

Comment: If you could mark my answer below as the solution for future users with the same problem, that'd be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `da` module only works in versions upwards of 10.1 in ArcGIS.  If you try to run a python code using `da` in ArcGIS 10 or below, you would get the error seen below:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'da'`

If you run the code in the correct version it should resolve itself. 
If you only have access to 10, then use the regular `arcpy.searchcursor` and adapt your code.
Penn state has a good resource for using search cursors and the differences between 10 and 10.1 .

[3.2.2 Reading through records](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/64)

Comment: GISKid,i have the same problem and i work with arcview 10.3, what can i do?

Comment: @Y.Y.C Maybe post another question with your code!